# c# send skype message to users unless textbox is empty

Tags: c#, winforms, skype, visual-c#-express-2010, skype4com

My Skype application has a fetcher that can send a message to people on the users contact list.  The contacts that the message is sent to are entered into text boxes.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var oskype = new SKYPE4COMLib.Skype();
          oskype.SendMessage(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text); //com error happens in this zone
            oskype.SendMessage(textBox11.Text, textBox2.Text);
            oskype.SendMessage(textBox3.Text, textBox2.Text);
            oskype.SendMessage(textBox4.Text, textBox2.Text);
            oskype.SendMessage(textBox5.Text, textBox2.Text);
            oskype.SendMessage(textBox6.Text, textBox2.Text);
            oskype.SendMessage(textBox7.Text, textBox2.Text);
            oskype.SendMessage(textBox8.Text, textBox2.Text);
            oskype.SendMessage(textBox9.Text, textBox2.Text);
            oskype.SendMessage(textBox10.Text, textBox2.Text);
}
```

I also have a RichTextBox that acts as a log, and when the message is sent, it writes to the log saying that the message was sent.  But when the text box is empty, it writes to the log "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: ", but instead I want it to write something like "Invalid Contact", or not write anything.

```
richTextBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine;
            richTextBox1.Text += "Sending message to :" + Environment.NewLine;
            richTextBox1.Text += textBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine;
            richTextBox1.Text += textBox11.Text + textBox3.Text + textBox4.Text + textBox5.Text + textBox6.Text + textBox7.Text + textBox8.Text + textBox9.Text + textBox10.Text;
```

And if the text entered into the text box in not on the persons contact list, it produces an error just basically saying that it cannot find that user but is there a way of making it ignore the empty text box and not try to send it to Skype?  If you need more detail, please just ask.

Comment: Regarding ignoring an empty textbox, what have you tried? It is not that hard to figure out.

Comment: @KendallFrey you helped my problem with it writing the unwanted information onto  the log but i still need to make it so that if there is a user that dose not exists it dose not cause an error but i don't know where to start

Comment: If you don't know where to start with that, maybe you should read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5011f09h.aspx.

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 1):

```
textBox11.Text + textBox3 + textBox4 + ...
```

You forgot to do `.Text` on most of them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Private bool checkBoxEmpty (textBox tb) {
    if (tb.text != ""){
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And just call this for each text box.

Hope it helps!